# JSENCODE - unterminated string literal

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use `JSENCODE` to prevent an un-terminated string literal in the following string:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/apex.js")}

var newRecords = [];
var appObj = new sforce.SObject("Application__c");
appObj.Id = "{!JSENCODE(AFC_Contract_Shell__c.ApplicationId__c)}";
appObj.eContract__c = true;
newRecords.push(appObj);

window.location.href = encodeURI('
https://composer.congamerge.com
?sessionId={!JSENCODE(API.Session_ID)}
&serverUrl={!JSENCODE(API.Partner_Server_URL_80)}
&id={!JSENCODE(AFC_Contract_Shell__c.Id)}
&QueryID=[BusinessAccount]a1Qa0000001uKKK,
[PrincipalContact]a1Qa0000001uKKO,
[FloorplanFee]a1Qa0000001uKKR,
[NumberofCurtailments]a1Qa0000001uKKM,
[Interest]a1Qa0000001uKKP,
[CurtailmentFee]a1Qa0000001uKKN,
[Principal]a1Qa0000001uKKH,
[BusType]a1Qa0000001uKKJ,
[DateInWords]a1Qa0000001uKKQ,
[CurtailmentTermWord]a1Qa0000001uKKL,
[PrincipalSum]a1Qa0000001uKKI,
[BusinessName]a1Qa0000001uKKF,
[GuarantorSig]a4G13000000LP1o?pv0={!JSENCODE(AFC_Contract_Shell__c.Id)},
[PrimarySig]a4G13000000LP1y?pv0={!JSENCODE(AFC_Contract_Shell__c.Id)}
&ReportID=[PContacts]00O13000008jhuD?pv0={!JSENCODE(AFC_Contract_Shell__c.ApplicationId__c)}


&LG0=0
&LG1=Contract+Generated
&LG4=1
&SelectTemplates=1
&Templategroup={!JSENCODE(CASE(AFC_Contract_Shell__c.Name,
"US Contract", "USAFCeContracts",
"US Amendment", "USAFCeContracts",
"California Contract", "CALAFCeContracts",
"California Amendment", "CALAFCeContracts",
"Canada Contract", "CANAFCeContracts",
"Canada Amendment", "CANAFCeContracts",
"AFC Credit"))}


&DocuSignVisible=1
&DS7=7
&DocuSignTag=1
&DocuSignEmailSubject={!JSENCODE(AFC_Contract_Shell__c.AFC_Dealer_ID__c)}+Your+AFC+Contract+is+Ready

&QVar0ID=a4G13000000LPCO?pv0={!JSENCODE(AFC_Contract_Shell__c.ApplicationId__c)}
&QVar1ID=a4G13000000LPCP?pv0={!JSENCODE(AFC_Contract_Shell__c.ApplicationId__c)}
&QVar2ID=a4G13000000LPCQ?pv0={!JSENCODE(AFC_Contract_Shell__c.ApplicationId__c)}
&QVar3ID=a4G13000000LPCR?pv0={!JSENCODE(AFC_Contract_Shell__c.ApplicationId__c)}

&DocuSignR1Id={Qvar0}
&DocuSignR1Type=Signer
&DocuSignR1Role=Signer+1
&DocuSignR1RoutingOrder=2
&DocuSignR1AccessCode={!JSENCODE(AFC_Contract_Shell__c.eContract_Access_Code__c)}
&DocuSignR1IdCheck=1
&DocuSignR1IdCheckType=RSA

&DocuSignR2Id={Qvar1}
&DocuSignR2Type=Signer
&DocuSignR2Role=Signer+2
&DocuSignR2RoutingOrder=2
&DocuSignR2AccessCode={!JSENCODE(AFC_Contract_Shell__c.eContract_Access_Code__c)}
&DocuSignR2IdCheck=1
&DocuSignR2IdCheckType=RSA

&DocuSignR3Id={Qvar2}
&DocuSignR3Type=Signer
&DocuSignR3Role=Signer+3
&DocuSignR3RoutingOrder=2
&DocuSignR3AccessCode={!JSENCODE(AFC_Contract_Shell__c.eContract_Access_Code__c)}
&DocuSignR3IdCheck=1
&DocuSignR3IdCheckType=RSA

&DocuSignR4Id={Qvar3}
&DocuSignR4Type=Signer
&DocuSignR4Role=Signer+4
&DocuSignR4RoutingOrder=2
&DocuSignR4AccessCode={!JSENCODE(AFC_Contract_Shell__c.eContract_Access_Code__c)}
&DocuSignR4IdCheck=1
&DocuSignR4IdCheckType=RSA

&DocusignR5Id={!JSENCODE(AFC_Contract_Shell__c.AFC_eContract_Role__c)}
&DocuSignR5Type=Approver
&DocuSignR5Role=Approver+5
&DocuSignR5RoutingOrder=1
&DocuSignR5IdCheck=0

&DocusignR6Id={!JSENCODE(AFC_Contract_Shell__c.AFC_Branch_Console_Owner__c)}
&DocuSignR6Type=Approver
&DocuSignR6Role=Approver+6
&DocuSignR6RoutingOrder=6
&DocuSignR6IdCheck=0
');
```

I have a custom button that I'm using `JavaScript` to update a few fields and then process the above URL to open in a new window.  I was trying `window.location.href` and `window.open()`, but both throw errors.

Comment: Please include the error text...

Comment: it was a syntax error...it did not give me any more detail with an error message.

Comment: do any of the values line "name" contain an apostrophe?

Comment: no apostrophe's, but there a double quotes. I'm trying to split each line into its own separate var and then concatenate together.  Seems like I shouldn't have to do that, but I'm giving it a try.

Comment: anyone know how to address this issue?

Comment: Can you post the complete javascript?

Comment: @Ashwani full code posted above

Answer (score 1):

Change following line

```
appObj.Id = {!AFC_Contract_Shell__c.ApplicationId__c};
```

to

```
appObj.Id = "{!JSENCODE(AFC_Contract_Shell__c.ApplicationId__c)}";
```

Also make sure that `window.location.href` does not contain any unclosed quote.

```
window.location.href = encodeURI('YOUR COMPLETE URL');
```

and put all `{!expression}` as `{!JSENCODE(expression)}`

Comment: I'm still getting unterminated string error. I'm checking on the unclosed quote.  Do the double quotes need to be escaped?

Comment: @Dman100 Updated answer.

Comment: I've added `encodeURI` to the full URL and I've wrapped all merge field expressions with `JSENCODE`.  I'm still getting un-terminated string issue.  I've updated the full code above.  Do you see anything I'm missing?

Comment: any other ideas what might be wrong with the URL?